# Grep Regex for Mac Address

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I need help with a regex to extract mac addresses from a large file.

Here is the format of the file:

```
Wed Apr 25 10:15:32 EDT 2012 Client: 00aa11bb22cc mac
Wed Apr 25 10:15:34 EDT 2012 Client: aa11bb22cc33 pc
```

Here is what I am currently trying with no luck:

```
grep -io '[0-9a-f]{12}' file.txt > macs.txt
```

Any ideas? I just want to extract only the mac address part into the file called `macs.txt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
grep -io '[0-9a-f]\{12\}' file.txt > macs.txt
```

Comment: Damn I knew I was close! haha Thanks a lot, I didn't realize I had to escape the brackets...

Comment: There's an O'Reilly book (Unix in a nutshell) I always used to refer to for variations in pattern matching between utilities. This particular variation was fresh in my mind

Comment: You can also use the `[:xdigit:]` [character class](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?grep#REGULAR_EXPRESSIONS) for which you don't need the `-i` option: `grep -o '[[:xdigit:]]\{12\}'`

Comment: @glennjackman: nice tip, didn't know there was a hexadecimal character class

Comment: For completeness sake, you may want to expand the the number group to [0-9a-fA-F]

Answer (score 2):

```
((([0-9a-fA-F]{2})[ :-]){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2})|(([0-9a-fA-F]){6}[
:-]([0-9a-fA-F]){6})|([0-9a-fA-F]{12})
```

I tested it against following expression that I know for MAC-Adresses. Depending on
the syntax of systems, firmwares and applikations.

```
F3 D3 A4 C1 99 E2
F3:D3:A4:C1:99:E2
F3-D3-A4-C1-99-E2
f3 d3 a4 c1 99 e2
f3:d3:a4:c1:99:e2
f3-d3-a4-c1-99-e2
f3d3a4 c199e2
f3d3a4:c199e2
f3d3a4-c199e2
f3d3a4c199e2
F3D3A4C199E2
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/^.*\([a-fA-F0-9]\{12\}\).*$/\1/' file.txt > macs.txt
```

Result:

```
00aa11bb22cc
aa11bb22cc33
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great as well. Any idea if this is faster than grep? My log files are fairly large...

Comment: @Alex_Hyzer_Kenoyer: I don't think so. As far as I know `sed` is pretty fast but `grep` usually is a big bet.

Answer (score 0):

egrep would work:

```
egrep -io '[0-9a-f]{12}' file.txt > macs.txt
```

There are 2 options for grep to handle regex,

```
grep -e
```

and

```
grep -E
```

One of them is equal to egrep and I guess now you know which. :)

Comment: how to use this with a pipe ? like cat txt | grep mac

Comment: Did you try `cat txt | egrep -io '[0-9a-f]{12}'? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This command line will extract all the MAC addresses from a regular file. It works on macOS.

It extracts from a regular file any MAC address on it. In the example, the regular file `file.txt` has mixed information including MAC addresses. The following command will extract them and save them on the `macs.txt` file.

`grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}' file.txt > macs.txt`

Comment: Please provide a description of what this does and how it helps.

Comment: That's a bold statement, actually.  If you use your regex against the sample data in [Henrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56668961/1394729) it returns just two lines.